# Insufficient privileges in NetworkManager with xmonad

Tags: networkmanager, privileges, xmonad

I have problem with Network Manager in xmonad. Let's say I want to connect to a new wireless network. When I try to do so, error is displayed, saying: "insufficient privileges". But when I try do do this with Gnome 3 there is no problem. And, when new network is added (using Gnome), I can now connect to this network when I am using xmonad.

I use Debian Sid, with 3.2.0-1-486 kernel, latest (0.10) version of xmonad. In xmonad, I use NetworkManager applet (0.9.2.0).

Part of my .xsession:

```
gnome-screensaver &
gnome-settings-daemon &
if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-applet ] ; then
    nm-applet --sm-disable &
fi
update-notifier &
exec xmonad
```

I suppose that I should add something to .xsession, but I am not sure about that.

I hope that you can give me some clues and maybe even a solution. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems with NetworkManager under AwesomeWM (sic!) (on a Ubuntu 11.10 system).

After fixing other permission related stuff I noticed that NM applet also needs a ConsoleKit session.

To check if this also your problem you can start the NM applet like this:

```
$ ck-launch-session nm-applet
```

(for testing purposes you can start it from an xterm)